# Eclipse multilingual spellchecker

Tags: eclipse

I'm using eclipse (4.3.0) and my current Java project contains comments both in english and russian. The problem is eclipse's spellchecker uses explicitly specified dictionary (`Preferences`, `General > Editors > Text Editors > Spelling`, `Platform dictionary`) and therefore highlights all russian words in the editor.

Is there a way to make eclipse's spellchecker accept several languages?

And BTW is there any russian dictionary for eclipse or the only way is to find a user defined russian dictionary and specify it in the preferences?